# Reverse for 'x' not found. 'x' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have three pages - homepage, http://127.0.0.1:8000/, displaying one paragraph sentence and two links in the header. and list of pizzas, http://127.0.0.1:8000/pizzas . Now i was trying to add links for each pizza on http://127.0.0.1:8000/pizzas page, so that one could click on them and see what toppings were available. I'm probably stuck because of my decision to use paths instead of url() for mapping urls, which the book i'm following uses.

**Error** : NoReverseMatch at /pizzas.
Reverse for 'pizza_w_toppings' not found. 'pizza_w_toppings' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

pizzas.html -

```html
{% extends "pizzeria_app/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1> Available Pizzas : </h1>
<ul>
{% for pizza in pizzas %}
 <li> <a href = {% url 'pizza_w_toppings' %}> {{pizza}}</a><li>
{% empty %}
  <p> We're outta Pizzas. next time bro! <p>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

app/urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
#homepage
path('', views.index),
#show available pizzas
path('pizzas', views.pizzas),
path('pizzas/<int:pizza_id>', views.pizza_w_toppings, name="pizza_w_toppings")
```

Views:
I'm new to StackOverflow and can't figure out how to add my views.py. i attached a picture, sorry
[views.py screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkvt2.png)

Comment: are you using `namespace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url tag should be `{% url 'pizza_w_toppings' pizza.id %}`. If you check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url), you'll see all possible variations of url tag.

> For example, suppose you have a view, app_views.client, whose URLconf
>   takes a client ID (here, client() is a method inside the views file
>   app_views.py). The URLconf line might look like this:
>
> `path('client/<int:id>/', app_views.client, name='app-views-client')`
>
> If this app’s URLconf is included into the project’s URLconf under a
>   path such as this:
>
> `path('clients/', include('project_name.app_name.urls'))`
>
> …then, in a template, you can create a link to this view like this:
>
> `{% url 'app-views-client' client.id %}`
>
> The template tag will output the string /clients/client/123/.

If you use namespaces, make sure to include namespace in your url tags like this:

`{% url 'your-namespace:app-views-client' client.id %}`

Comment: `Reverse for 'pizza_w_toppings' not found. 'pizza_w_toppings' is not a valid view function or pattern name`. based on the traceback, it's a good point, but if it was an argument  issue, Django would not say `is not a valid view function or pattern name`, it would say instead `"url with argument {"":""}` bla bla

Comment: Thanks, that's one of the mistakes. but error still persists.

Comment: @IrakliTchigladze, then pretty much the only thing that is left is `namespace` issue, as @Lemayzeur pointed out. You probably have defined `app_name = 'your_app_name_here'` above `urlpatterns` and in this case you have to use this syntax: `{% url 'your_app_name_here:pizza_w_toppings' pizza.id %}`.

Comment: That worked!! thanks so much. what do you mean by "above urlpatterns" though? You mean the urls.py in the main project folder, in which i point to my urls.py in app folder?

Comment: Nevermind that "above urlpaterns" if you got it working. `app_name` is usually defined somewhere on top in the apps urls.py, but that's not a rule.

Comment: Good structured answers are priceless they continue to be helpful for a very long time just helped me here @Borut